# Passing environment variables to XCUITest

Tags: xcode, testing, continuous-integration, xctest, xcuitest

I run UI tests on CI/CD provider (like CircleCI), I need to read multiple secret environment variables (like testing username and password). I could easily set it but I don't understand how to pass them properly to test cases.

I found 2 ways to do that:

1. Store it inside shared scheme (in *XCode Arguments*), it's a bad idea because that secrets shouldn't be stored in git repo.
2. Injecting variables via text replacement in Swift / Obj-C / xconfig files (like small perl scripts). I don't think that is a good way in 2020.

I use fastlane but haven't found anything about that.

How to do that properly?

Comment: What provider do you use? I think this functionality should be on their side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with Xcode 7, [environment variables are no longer being passed on](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016994-CH5-SW30) to the test binary.

But, you could pass the environment variable as a build setting and then redefine it as an environment variable for test invocation using the Xcode test scheme configuration.

For example, assuming you have an environment variable defined called `YOUR_SECRET_ENV_VAR`, to pass it to Xcode as a build setting from the command line:

```sh
xcrun xcodebuild test
    -workspace your-app.xcworkspace
    -scheme your-app
    -destination 'platform=iOS,name=iPhone'
    YOUR_SECRET_BUILD_VAR=$YOUR_SECRET_ENV_VAR
```

Then, feed this build setting into your scheme configuration as an environment variable for test invocation. You'll have to uncheck `User the Run action's arguments and environment variables`.

[image: configuring environment variables in scheme settings in Xcode UI]

Finally, make use of the environment variable in your test code, using:

```swift
let yourSecret = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["YOUR_SECRET_ENV_VAR"]
```

Comment: How could I use it on a local machine as well if OS environment won't be used? I could run `xcodebuild` on CI but it will be uncomfortable to use it locally. I couldn't insert secret keys in XCode scheme because it will be committed to git.

Comment: I haven't tried this on the latest Xcode, but apparently you can opt out of environment variables sanitization behaviour  using
`defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode UseSanitizedBuildSystemEnvironment -bool NO` for the Xcode app
or by passing
`-UseSanitizedBuildSystemEnvironment=NO` to `xcodebuild` when invoking from the command line.

Comment: @marius It looks like the `UseSanitizedBuildSystemEnvironment` flag is not supported anymore.

Comment: In that case I would just always run tests locally from the command line, I wouldn't use the Xcode UI. Perhaps there is something that can be done with storing the secret value in an `.xcconfig` file that is ignored in version control? Another avenue to explore would be to have a pre-action in the scheme that runs a script that would prompt the developer for the secret value, see more here https://scriptingosx.com/2018/08/user-interaction-from-bash-scripts/ .

Comment: You can keep your Xcode scheme out of git pretty easily. First, uncheck Shared at the bottom. Then I think just make sure you gitignore `xcuserdata/`.